# Example for nonzero covariance when expectation of product of two random variables is zero?

Tags: statistics, least-squares

Suppose there are two random variables $x,y$, with nonzero means. Their covariance is
$$Cov(x,y)=E(xy)-E(x)E(y).$$
If they are independent, $E(xy)=E(x)E(y)$ and hence $Cov(x,y)=0$.

However, is it possible that $Cov(x,y)\neq0$ due to $E(xy)=0$ and $E(x)E(y)\neq0$? I can't think of/visualize an example.

(I'm asking because I'm trying to gain some intuition behind the algebra of the least squares formula, where $\beta=E[(X'X)]^{-1}E[X'y]$ in the population. I'm well aware that the estimator $\hat{\beta}$ ultimately involves $(X'MX)^{-1}$ and $X'MY$ when an intercept is included, where $M$ is the demeaning matrix.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example: Suppose $Y$ and $Z$ satisfy (i) $\Bbb E[Y]=1$, $\Bbb E[Z]=0$, (ii) $Var[Y]=Var[Z]=1$, and (iii) $Cov[Y,Z]=\rho>0$. Define $X=Z-\rho$. Then $\Bbb E[XY]=\Bbb E[ZY]-\Bbb E[\rho Y]=Cov[Z,Y]-\rho=0$, but $Cov[X,Y]=Cov[Z,Y]=\rho>0$.

Comment: Thank you John! Can I ask you about some (geometrical) intuition here? I take it you took two RV's that were neither orthogonal nor independent and you shifted the second one downwards by subtracting a constant, just enough to ensure that the resulting variables are now orthogonal, yet still dependent. (So there is really not much to learn from orthogonality unless I know (or assume) that one variable is mean zero, am I right?) Can you think of a quick way to visualize the example you scetched (of course I'm not asking you to actually do that!)?

Comment: Perhaps the message is that if you want to think of covariance in geometric terms it is best to think in terms of the *centered* random variables $X-\Bbb E(X)$ and $Y-\Bbb E(Y)$, and their orthogonality in the usual $L^2$ sense.